# Django map model data to external data

Tags: python, django, django-models, microsoft-graph-api

I want to map data from the https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer api as a data source to have the additional required data on the model.

Using a computed property on the model does not work as it is going to query for each instance in the set and is too time consuming.

I could not find anything on this topic, besides maybe abusing the from_db() method as an override, if this even works.

TLDR; I want data from an external API on my local model

Comment: Have you looked at MS Graph SDK or its's metadata?

Comment: I scrapped the idea of mapping the data and added a scheduled script to sync the API data to my local DB